# Rsync just...stops

Tags: rsync

I use StoreBackup to make backups on a local machine. Periodically, I copy the entire directory of backups to an external drive, as an off-site backup. To make this copy, I have a really simple rsync command:

```
rsync -aHv --delete /backups /media/brad/Backups
```

This command used to work reliably. However, for the past year or so, it sometimes just... stops.

There is no error message. It just stops, as though it thinks it has finished. Usually, this is during the deletion phase. I can restart it and it will usually finish. Sometimes, I have to restart it twice. This is rsync 3.2.7 running unter Ubuntu 22.04.

Any ideas?

Edit: The command is run using sudo, so privileges are not an issue.

Comment: have you checked the log when it stops? perhaps a `dmesg` to be sure it's not a problem  on the external disk.

Comment: What is the target filesystem type?

Comment: There shouldn't be a deletion phase as such unless you're using an old version of `rsync`. Try adding `--delete-during`

Comment: @D'Arcy Nader: Which log file? There are no related error messages in any log files in /var/log.

Comment: @roaima: Both file systems are ext4

Comment: did you try to copy to another external disk with the same filesystem (ext4) and the same directory tree? why do you use -H you cannot preserve hard links across different filesystem as far as i know.

Comment: @D'ArcyNader the `-H` preserves hard links within the tree that's being copied. Not between source and destination

Comment: @roaima ah i get it now, thank you .